# Do all arguments have to be included in a Javascript function call?

Tags: javascript, syntax

If you have a func

```
function myFunc(a,b,c)
{
    if(c) alert("c got here!");
}
```

does EVERY call you make to the func have to be like

```
myFunc(1,2,3)
```

or is it ok for some calls to be just

```
myFunc(1,2)
```

?

I'm finding that the latter works, but I'm wondering if it works across all browsers.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to include every paramater, but you **must** use the first two **if** you need to use the third.

If the function signature has 3 params, and you only provide two when you invoke it, then the third argument will evaluate to `undefined` inside the function.

You can also provide defaults inside the function if you want:

```
function doStuff(a, b, c) {
    // if c is not defined, use default value
    c = (typeof c === 'undefined') ? 3.14 : c;
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you jahroy - cleared it up perfectly for me. Great explanation.